# Help with linq join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I have the following expression in linq (its a join) and i am selecting into "J" because i need to use J later (currently i just selecting J but once i have this fixed i plan on use J within another subquery after)

But it won't let me supply a where using the "V" side hence v.IdOFfice is invalid.
I have tried swapping around the joins and that what happens i can't use the "GVT"..

WIth specifying the where it works perfect but i need to specify 2 wheres that are present in the 2 tables  ... hence IdOffice  and IdTariff are in there own tables .. they are not both ....

```
(from gvt in Tariffs
join v in Items
on gvt.IdGroupItem equals v.IdGroupItem 
into j
where v.IdOffice == 1 && gvt.IdTariff == 111
select j).Take(50)
```

Probably something silly, it appears the table specified after the join i am not able to use in the where?

Any ideas?

Thanks

This is basically what i am trying to achieve

```
from gvt in Tariffs
  join v in Items
  on gvt.IdGroupItem equals v.IdGroupItem 
  into j
  where v.IdOffice == 1 && gvt.IdTariff == 111
  select new
  {
      id = v.IdItem
      Tariff = from j
      {
    test = j.TariffDesc,
        test1 = j.TariffPrice
      }
```

basicaly i end up with 1 record with Id and a field which as many tariffs inside - if this makes sense?

}

Query working great,

it would be nice to be able to use an extension method (c#) like so ... is this possible so i can dynamically set tariff ... so for example i do the query and i have an extension method (which i already use on simple queries) like so

```
    public static IQueryable<Models.ItemTariffCol> WithTariffId(this IQueryable<Models.ItemTariffCol> qry, int tariffId)
    {
        return from t in qry
               where t.IdTarifa == tariffId
               select t;
    }
```

this makes it very extensible ?  If its a normal where i can do this but the query isn't in the where

Thank you.

Comment: Your example with extension method should work fine as it is written; can you clarify what the question is regarding it?

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I am going to insert into my code and try and check the extension method on it and i will check back shortly if thats ok.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a *group join* here, since you're using `into`. This means that for every `gvt`, you have not one `Item`, but possibly several (or none). The list of all items is stored in `j`, as an `IEnumerable<Item>`. If you want to select all tariffs for which there's at least one item with `IdOffice == 1`, then you can do it like this:

```
from gvt in Tariffs
join v in Items
     on gvt.IdGroupItem equals v.IdGroupItem 
     into j
where gvt.IdTariff == 111 && j.Any(v => v.IdOffice == 1)
...
```

After the answer edit, it seems that you've started from the wrong direction as well - so far as I can see, you want a list of tariffs for every item, not the list of items for every tariff. For that, you need to reverse your join:

```
from item in Items
join tariff in Tariffs
     on item.IdGroupItem equals tariff.IdGroupItem 
     into tariffs
where item.IdOffice == 1
select new
{
    Id = item.IdItem,
    Tariffs = from tariff in tariffs
              where tariff.IdTariff == 111
              select new { tariff.TariffDesc, tariff.TariffPrice }
}
```

Or you could filter tariffs right in the join:

```
from item in Items
join tariff in (from t in Tariffs where t.IdTariff == 111 select t)
     on item.IdGroupItem equals tariff.IdGroupItem 
     into tariffs
where item.IdOffice == 1
select new
{
    Id = item.IdItem,
    Tariffs = from tariff in tariffs
              select new { tariff.TariffDesc, tariff.TariffPrice }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PAvel, i updated my original question with basically what i am trying to achieve, as you will see i am using J further down.. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you very much this works great!, I wonder if i can bother you 1 last time.. I need the query to be extensible with extension methods .. i will update my question so i can use code formatting...

Comment: I have updated my original question, i think i have explained it correctly.... Thanks for your continued help....

Comment: to be more specific with item.IdOffice i can use a simple extension method so i can pass it a value using the extension method hence the original query retrusn everything and with the ext method i can say WithOfficeId(1)  for example

Comment: You'd just remove `where` from the query in my answer, and filter over `Id` field in your extension method, then. However, you'd need to define a named type then, since you can't declare a method (extension or no) taking an argument of anonymous type.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, everything seems to work now .. A big thank you.. i will accept the answer above - you really helped..